# Having problems with Laravel Migrations

Tags: laravel, migration

I have added all my  in constraints 2020_06_17_221942_create_constraints_table
but its not working 
All migrations  successfully done but without any table  constraints the 2020_06_17_221942_create_constraints_table is :

```
    Schema::table('seasons', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('best_project_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('manager_id');
        $table->foreign('best_project_id')->references('id')->on('projects');
        $table->foreign('manager_id')->references('id')->on('users');

    });
    Schema::table('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');;


    });

    Schema::table('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('study_major_id')->references('id')->on('study_majors');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('Users');

        $table->foreign('season_id')->references('id')->on('Seasons');
    })
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "Blueprint" type-hinting to the migration function. It should work

For example:

```
Schema::table('seasons', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('best_project_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('manager_id');
        $table->foreign('best_project_id')->references('id')->on('projects');
        $table->foreign('manager_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

Comment: Quick Question: Do the "seasons" table already exists in DB and you are writing a modification migration on top of it, right?

Comment: Yes, 
first i have migrate all the tables , then i am trying to migrate this

Comment: Couple Questions:

1. Did you check at the DB level to check if the constraints are added or not? If it is Mysql/MariaDB, you can run 'describe seasons' to check.

2. Can you share the complete code of the migration file?

Comment: Yes i checked  
The result :
CREATE TABLE `seasons` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `best_project_ID` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `seasons_best_project_id_foreign` (`best_project_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: there is no constraints  :/

Comment: You need to run "describe seasons" inside MySQL console to get the output. You can share here once you get it.

Comment: sometimes if just one table is not InnoDB constraints won't happen properly

Comment: MySQL/my_tamayuz_db/  http://127.0.0.1:8080/phpmyadmin/db_sql.php?db=my_tamayuz_db
Your SQL query has been executed successfully.

describe seasons



id bigint(20) unsigned NO PRI 
    NULL
 auto_increment 
name varchar(255) NO  
    NULL
  
created_at timestamp YES  
    NULL
  
updated_at timestamp YES  
    NULL
  
best_project_ID bigint(20) unsigned YES MUL 
    NULL

Comment: Check table `migrations` for `2020_06_17_221942_create_constraints_table`. When it's there - delete this record and rerun migrations.

Comment: As @kevind pointed out, Did you try to check the engine of all tables that you are using in foreign key references? You can do so by running "SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'table name'"

Comment: Your migration won't work. Because `seasons` and `projects` table conflict each other. Example : on your `seasons` table you make a relation with `projects` but `projects` table is not migrated yet those time. Hope you undwerstand your error.

Comment: @TalhaF. The catch here is that all tables are already there in the DB. This is a modification migration and not some creation migration.

Comment: Thanks for replaying 
not working
the problem is in My SQL
but i don't know witch part of it .

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last query with this

```
Schema::table('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->unsignedBigInteger('study_major_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('season_id');
    $table->foreign('study_major_id')->references('id')->on('study_majors');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('Users');
    $table->foreign('season_id')->references('id')->on('Seasons');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying 
not working
the problem is in My SQL
but i don't know witch part of it .